# When adding a new Migration the table name is changed by the Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add a new table (model) to my database.

- I named the model as **TutorScheduler**
- The controller as **TutorsSchedulerController**

I want to name the actual table as **TutorsScheduler** as shown below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{     
     public DbSet<TutorScheduler> TutorsScheduler { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I run the migration, the script that's generated renames my table to **TutorSchedulers** instead as shown below.

```
 CreateTable(
    "dbo.TutorSchedulers",
    c => new
        {
           Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
           StartDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
           EndDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
           TutorName = c.String(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

I am using EntityFramework version: 6.1.3, Visual Studio Version 15.4.2 and SQLServer 2017.  My other tables are named as I expected apart from this one. I just want to know why this is happening and how I should fix it. Any help will be appropriated. Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Should I leave this question or delete it since it is duplicate?

Comment: If others having the same problem come across this question, then they know where to find the answer. But if you want to delete it, then its up to you. As a side note, answers do not go in the question and I have rolled back your edit